# Referencing an index in an array in SMARTY template

Tags: php, arrays, reference, indexing, smarty

I have a variable that is an array in Smarty, and I am trying to figure out how to retrieve that information. The variable is called $COMMENTS and I did `$COMMENTS|@print_r` and this is what I got:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => ModComments_CommentsModel Object ( 
        [data:private] => Array ( 
            [0] => 11686 
            [crmid] => 11686 
            [1] => 1679 
            [smcreatorid] => 1679 
            [2] => 1679 
            [smownerid] => 1679 
            [3] => 0 
            [modifiedby] => 0 
            [4] => ModComments 
            [setype] => ModComments 
            [5] => 
            [description] => 
            [6] => 2011-06-08 15:00:31 
            [createdtime] => 2011-06-08 15:00:31 
            [7] => 2011-06-08 15:00:31 
            [modifiedtime] => 2011-06-08 15:00:31 
            [8] => 2011-06-29 12:00:23 
            [viewedtime] => 2011-06-29 12:00:23 
            [9] => 
            [status] => 
            [10] => 0 
            [version] => 0 
            [11] => 1 
            [presence] => 1 
            [12] => 0 
            [deleted] => 0 
            [13] => 11686 
            [modcommentsid] => 11686 
            [14] => aasd 
            [commentcontent] => aasd 
            [15] => 6730 
            [related_to] => 6730 
            [16] => 
            [parent_comments] => 
            [17] => 11686 
        )
    )
    [1] => ModComments_CommentsModel Object ( 
        [data:private] => Array ( 
            [0] => 11685 
            [crmid] => 11685 
            [1] => 1679 
            [smcreatorid] => 1679 
            [2] => 1679 
            [smownerid] => 1679 
            [3] => 0 
            [modifiedby] => 0 
            [4] => ModComments 
            [setype] => ModComments 
            [5] => 
            [description] => 
            [6] => 2011-06-08 14:58:42 
            [createdtime] => 2011-06-08 14:58:42 
            [7] => 2011-06-08 14:58:42 
            [modifiedtime] => 2011-06-08 14:58:42 
            [8] => 
            [viewedtime] => 
            [9] => 
            [status] => 
            [10] => 0 
            [version] => 0 
            [11] => 1 
            [presence] => 1 
            [12] => 0 
            [deleted] => 0 
            [13] => 11685 
            [modcommentsid] => 11685 
            [14] => comment 
            [commentcontent] => comment 
            [15] => 6730 
            [related_to] => 6730 
            [16] => 
            [parent_comments] => 
            [17] => 11685
        )
    )
    [2] => ModComments_CommentsModel Object ( 
        [data:private] => Array ( 
            [0] => 6731 
            [crmid] => 6731 
            [1] => 1679 
            [smcreatorid] => 1679 
            [2] => 1679 
            [smownerid] => 1679 
            [3] => 0 
            [modifiedby] => 0 
            [4] => ModComments 
            [setype] => ModComments 
            [5] => 
            [description] => 
            [6] => 2010-11-02 10:15:06 
            [createdtime] => 2010-11-02 10:15:06 
            [7] => 2010-11-02 10:15:06 
            [modifiedtime] => 2010-11-02 10:15:06 
            [8] => 
            [viewedtime] => 
            [9] => 
            [status] => 
            [10] => 0 
            [version] => 0 
            [11] => 1 
            [presence] => 1 
            [12] => 0 
            [deleted] => 0 
            [13] => 6731 
            [modcommentsid] => 6731 
            [14] => Test comment 
            [commentcontent] => Test comment 
            [15] => 6730 
            [related_to] => 6730 
            [16] => 
            [parent_comments] => 
            [17] => 6731
        ) 
    )
)
```

I am trying to retrieve the **11686** number from that. Any help? I have tried `$COMMENTS[0][data:private][0]` but that didn't work.

Any help greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, put `print_r()` output into `<pre>` tags so it is readable.

```
Array ( 
    [0] => ModComments_CommentsModel Object ( 
        [data:private] => Array ( 
            [0] => 11686 
            [crmid] => 11686 
            [1] => 1679 
            [smcreatorid] => 1679 
            [2] => 1679 
            ...
        )
    )
    ...
)
```

You're trying to access the first object in your array, `$COMMENTS[0]`. Since that it is object, and your `data` property is private, you cannot access it in Smarty. You would have to edit the ModComments_CommentsModel class to give you access to either the `data` property or the `crmid` key of the property.

Example:

```
class ModComments_CommentsModel {

    // ...

    public function CrmId(){
        return $this->data['crmid'];
    }

    // ...

}
```

---

```
{* template *}
{$COMMENTS[0]->CrmId()}

{* might have to assign before using method call *}
{assign var='comment' value=$COMMENTS[0]}
{$comment->CrmId()}
```